# I'm getting this same error while trying to make a streamlit app

Tags: python, github, streamlit

can anyone identify this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iojl.png)

How to overcome this error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: This app has encountered an error. 
The original error message is redacted to prevent data leaks.
Full error details have been recorded in the logs (if you're on Streamlit Cloud, click on 'Manage app' in the lower right of your app).

Traceback:
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py",
line 535, in _run_script
     exec(code, module.__dict__) File "/mount/src/streamlit-example/streamlit_app.py", line 3, in <module>
     from apiclient.discovery import build`
```

Comment: Why was this tagged with github?

Comment: Would be good if you could show your code.  Especially where do u include your libraries? It is a common error for the wrong named requirments.txt error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably get this error because you added and read the packages to txt with a different name instead of **requirements.txt**.

Elements in **requirements.txt** should have a format like that. (Use your libraries I just gave an example)

Ex:

```
pandas
plotly
streamlit
pandas-datareader
```